# HTML Cannot Get Input Color Value

Tags: javascript, html, html-input

I am trying to get color input in HTML, and I cannot get the value the user has selected. This is my code:

```js
function setColor() {
  alert(document.getElementById("colorPicker").value)
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="setColor()">Set Color</button>
<input type="color" name="colorPicker" value="#ff0000">
```

Comment: Well for starters you have no element with the ID of colorPicker

Comment: That's a typo, `getElementById` clearly needs an ID, wouldn't you think ?

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to select the `input` via its ID (i.e. `getElementById()`), but the element does not have an ID, only a name. Update your `<input />` to include the `id` attribute as follows:

```js
function setColor() 
{
 alert(document.getElementById("colorPicker").value)
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="setColor()">Set Color</button>
<input type="color" id="colorPicker" name="colorPicker" value="#ff0000" />
```

Answer (score 0):

there is no such element with the id "colorPicker".
you should set the input `id="colorPicker"` instead

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function setColor() {
alert(document.getElementById("colorPicker").value)
}
</script>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#808080">

<button type="button" onclick="setColor()">Set Color</button>
<input type="color" name="colorPicker" id="colorPicker" value="#ff0000">

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few things wrong in your code

1. you have created a button with type button
   2.It is not a good practice to mix your mark up with javascript.

Check the following code snippet

```js
window.onload=function(){
  var el = document.getElementById("button1");
el.addEventListener("click", setColor);
}
function setColor() {
alert(document.getElementById("colorPicker").value);
}
```

```html
<body bgcolor="#808080">

<input type="button" id="button1"  value="Set Color"></input>
<input type="color" id="colorPicker" value="#ff0000">
</body>
```

Answer (score -2):

Add to the input element an 'id' attribute with a 'colorPicker' value.

Seems like you are trying to select the input by using 'getElementById' and it actually has no id

Comment: An explanation of why would be useful

Comment: Better to recommend *adding* an `id` attribute. `name` may be used for something else.